# Two road warrior clients behind the same NAT device (IKEv2, StrongSwan, LibreSwan)

Tags: linux, vpn, remote-access, ipsec, strongswan

I have an IKEv2 VPN that is set up and works properly, however I run into issues when I have two road warriors behind the same NAT device.  Both devices connect however the second device seems to kick the first device off.  I believe this is related to the fact that they are using the same ports for NAT-T so the firewall that the road warriors are behind doesn't know where to send the packets.  The IPSEC box is not behind a NAT.

Comment: The device doing NAT can't distinguish the two. The canonical solution for this is IPv6.

Comment: What does "seems to kick the first device off" mean exactly? Is there anything logged to that end on the server? Do the clients use different identities? Did you try capturing traffic to see where the packets get lost? Are you actually using strongSwan or Libreswan?